# Открытие нескольких txt файлов из проводника в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Допустим есть некоторые .txt файлы могу ли я, открыв каталог в котором они находятся, вывести имена файлов и их компоненты(допустим имя файла сопоставимо с именем человека, а внутри его данные), а также смогу ли я взаимодействовать с компонентами(сортировать, искать и т.д). Подскажите если не трудно как это можно сделать или ссылки которые помогли бы реализовать похожий функционал.

Comment: Вы что-то странное и запутанное написали, требую пояснительную бригаду. Вам нужно список файлов из каталога получить надо? Потом в цикле прочитать каждый файл и достать из него что-то? Да, можно. `foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(dir))`

Comment: @aepot В Winform'ах используя OpenDialog открыть папку с .txt файлами (тут либо при нажатии на папку вывести имена .txt(а также их содержимое) файлов которые в ней находятся или после перехода в неё выбрать не менее 2х файлов для работы)

Comment: Быть может FolderBrowserDialog лучше подойдет в таком случае

Comment: @aepot Может быть